# Accessing a chart's source data cells

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, excel-2007

What is the best way to access the cells that provide the data to a chart in Excel 2007 (using .Net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find to do this was to retrieve the `Formula` property and parse that.